# Python function parameter type dependencies

Tags: python, types, typing, static-typing, duck-typing

Here is a function that enforces a dependency between the types of its arguments:

```py
def example(a: Optional[int], b: Optional[int]) -> int:
    if a is None and b is None:
        raise TypeError("One of a and b can be None, but not both.")
    return 42
```

- Is there a way to express this dependency in Python's type annotation syntax instead of or in addition to the runtime check?
- Is this possible in other programming languages?
- Does this dependency concept have a name and theory associated with it that can be studied?

Comment: You can use [`@typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload).

Comment: Good suggestion! Don't know why I did not think of this.

Comment: The most basic solution, if the two arguments are interchangeable (e.g., as in `a + b`), would be to make the first one required, and the second optional.

Comment: @Hans: In this case that would be a feasible solution, but I am thinking more broadly where a and b are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Gregory: Partly: As suggested earlier the overload decorator might be usable in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency seems to be an example of a precondition in the context of [Design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)  - the Wikipedia page lists a number of programming languages which support this in varying degrees. E.g., in Eiffel a function is qualified with a `require` for this purpose.

While I believe Python has no native mechanism to formalize preconditions, the Wikipedia page lists a few libraries. From cursory inspection, these do not seem to handle inter-argument preconditions like your example. (Interestingly, there is a deferred PEP from 2003 which would allow for this by a simple specification in the docstring: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0316/)

To be honest I am not sure if `@typing.overload` will help much in this case, but I would interested to see a solution based on it.

While it might be overkill for the example you spell out, if you have more arguments and/or more complex dependencies between them, an alternative approach may be to encapsulate the arguments in a parameter object (see, e.g., https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html), and have a factory or builder for that parameter object which makes the requirements clear.

Comment: I mean, `overload` seems like it would work, but it would be verbose. Design by contract seems to be very close to the concept I had in mind. Thanks for bringing it up!

The parameter object is also a viable solution.